# I am having a problem with pandas trying to make a table displaying statistics from a file

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

```
import pandas

link = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dvanderelst-python-class/python-class/spring2021/assignment_data/young_people_survey.csv'
data = pandas.read_csv(link,index_col=0)

grp = data.groupby(['Gender','Smoking','Healthy eating'])
mns = grp.mean()
 
mns = grp.mean()
std = grp.std()

mns_reset_indices = mns.reset_index()

result = data.groupby(data, ['Gender','Smoking','Healthy eating'])

table = result.pivot(index='Gender', columns='Smoking', values='Healthy Eating')
print(table)
```

I need to create a table displaying something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8IOs.png

I keep getting an error like this:
[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsmF4.png)

Comment: Your question seems incomplete, what is the problem you are having, do you have an error, unexpected output etc. Please put these in the question as well :).

Comment: I am getting an error saying there is an unhashable type: 'list'. I and the data set doesn't just use Gender, Smoking, and Healthy eating it still has the rest of the data so it isn't splitting it up.

Comment: Please update the question with the error traceback.

Comment: `data.groupby(data, ['Gender','Smoking','Healthy eating'])` --> `data.groupby(['Gender','Smoking','Healthy eating'])`. Why are you using `pivot`???

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should be :

```
df.groupby(['Gender', 'Smoking']).agg(np.mean)
```

[image]

using `pivot_table`:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Gender', 'Smoking'], columns=None, values=['Healthy eating'],
           aggfunc={'Healthy eating':[np.std, np.mean]},fill_value=0)
```

**table:**

[image]